# Accessing Data from Database for display

Tags: html, angular, typescript

UPDATE: I figure it would be easier if I just made a Gist to share with the code that's being utilized in this.

CODE: https://gist.github.com/strawmr/15a22bf5118642ff130f215511982b80

---

ORIGINAL: I'm working on a new system at work that will allow data to be read and updated directly to a database. Part of this involves Angular 2 and Typescript.

During the development I've run into an issue with it not loading the information. It shows me solely the "loading incidents" that is used as a placeholder inside the element tags.

What could I be missing that is causing the data to not appear or the code itself to not function properly? Below are the code snippets.

**incident.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { SpringfieldService } from "./springfield.service";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Incident } from "./incident";

@Injectable()
export class IncidentService extends SpringfieldService {
private url = this.baseUrl + "Incident";

constructor(private http: Http) {
    super();

}

getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getIncident(incidentId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.url, incidentId)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

saveIncident(incident: Incident) {
    return this.http.put(this.url, incident)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

addIncident(incident: Incident) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, incident)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

deleteIncident(incident: Incident) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url, incident)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

}
```

**incident.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { IncidentService } from "./incident.service";
import { Incident } from "./incident";

@Component({
selector: "rpcs-incident",
templateUrl: "/app/incident.component.html",
providers: [IncidentService]
})
export class IncidentComponent {
private incidents: Incident[];

constructor(incidentService: IncidentService) {
    incidentService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
        response => this.incidents = response,
        err => console.log("Error: ", err),
        () => console.log("Fetch incidents complete.", this.incidents)
        );
}

}
```

**incident.component.html**

```
<div class="incidentarticle" *ngFor="let incident of incidents; let i =    index; trackBy: incidentId">
<h2>
    {{incident.IncidentId}}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" (click)="onEdit()"></span>
</h2>
<h3 *ngIf="incident.DateReported != null">Start: {{incident.DateReported | date:'medium'}}</h3>


<!--<div> <span>Applies To:</span> {{newsitem.AppliesTo}}</div>-->


<div>
    <span>Description:</span> {{incident.IncidentDescription}}
</div>

<!--<div>
    <span>Action Required:</span> {{newsitem.ActionRequired}}
</div>

<div><span>For Further Information:</span> {{newsitem.AdditionalInfo}}</div>-->
```

Comment: Open your  browser console (depends on browser/OS but it's the  F12 key on most windows browsers), do you see any errors being reported?

Comment: A database might lock all requests for some reason

Comment: @JimL "The selector "rpcs-incident" did not match any elements" is the error that appears. Though, that only occurs on pages that won't show the data. When I get to the page where the data will show, that error doesn't appear

Comment: Double check your app.module.ts or whatever NgModule this is supposed to be in and make sure the service is in the providers array and the component is in the declarations array.

Comment: @JimL here's what I have in my app.module.ts:  
  `declarations: [ NewsComponent, IncidentComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ NewsComponent, IncidentComponent ]`

Comment: at a minimum, you also need to have a providers:[IncidentService]  along side the declarations and the corresponding import statement near the top of the file. If you're using Angular.Cli to generate your bits and pieces, last that I checked it does not automatically put them in the app.module.

Comment: I do have the import already: import { IncidentComponent } from "./incident.component";  And I do have a providers in my incident.component.ts. I added it to the app.module, but that didn't appear to work.

Comment: can you please provide your `AppModule` code and the template where you use the selector `<rpcs-incident></rpcs-incident>` ?

Comment: @mickdev I've updated the question post with the information you requested.

Comment: can you test this : `template :'<p>Incidents Works ! </p>' ` instead of that `templateUrl: "/app/incident.component.html",` ?

Comment: @mickdev I replaced the line, but I still get just the "...Loading Incidents" placeholder on the page.

Comment: Ok then try to implement OnInit. `export class IncidentComponent implement OnInit`. Then: `ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Called in IncidentComponent...')
  }`. Open your browser console and tell me if you see the log.

Comment: Now I'm getting: "Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for IncidentService! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: DI Error Error: DI Error"

Comment: The idea here is to narrow down the possible issues. Try to comment all codes in `incident.component.ts` except ngOnInit() code. Check your console. If it's display the log properly, so you'll have to check your service implementation ...

Comment: I commented out the code, but the log isn't displaying

Comment: Wait ! You inject a component in your provider ? `providers: [IncidentComponent]`

Comment: Yes. That's what we are doing for the news method that we are running, and it works fine. But, for some reason, the incident version of doing it the same way won't work.

Comment: I think you shouldn't do that in the first place. Only a service are registered in the provider according to the doc : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html Anyway, this might be your issue. I recommend that you implement your service properly

Comment: I kind of figured out the issue. It lays with my App.Module.TS. If <rpcs-news> isn't there, <rpcs-incident> won't call in.  That being said. Is there a way to call in <rpcs-incident> without needing <rpcs-news> as well?